# How to reduce no of lines of code for repeating codes.?

Tags: php, function

I am using below code for inserting image into DB for many times, So how can I specifically convert this code into a simple function or maybe similar to that so that I can reduce my number of lines of codes?

```
include 'template_imagefunction.php';
if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "category/".$imagename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
        $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `category` (`cat_name`, `parent`, `cat_status`,`cat_image`) VALUES ('$catname', '--', '$status','$target_path') ");
        header('Location: categoryylisting1.php');
    }
    else {
        exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1. put it into a function - 2. define the parameters and 3. replace the copy&page-code by your new function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) define the function like this

```
function upload($_FILES)
{

if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "category/".$imagename;
   if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
      $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `category` (`cat_name`, `parent`, `cat_status`,`cat_image`) VALUES ('$catname', '--', '$status','$target_path') ");
      header('Location: categoryylisting1.php');
}
else {
      exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 
  }

   }
```

2)call the function with parameter

```
upload($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

use array for adding multiple options in single function